# Track REST API calls using google analytics/

Tags: python, django, rest, google-analytics, django-rest-framework

I want to track which resources are popular using the data from google analytics.
Is this possible with google analytics?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464863/is-there-a-google-analytics-like-solution-to-track-rest-calls-to-a-web-service

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you would like to use google analytics?

You can instead log it to a log file with the python [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

You can also write it to a database (use [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/) for free if you are only counting).

Alternatively see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464863/is-there-a-google-analytics-like-solution-to-track-rest-calls-to-a-web-service).